# Embed MVC Partial View into a document.write JS call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a Javascript file that will be embedded onto a 3rd party site. The Javascript file will render some content onto the third party site. The idea is the same as Google Adsense - web site owner places a JS file on their site, and some advertisements appear in that location.

I am open to alternative methods, but I am trying to accomplish this by having the embedded JS file simply do:

document.write('Advertisement content')

However, my advertisement content is embedded in ASP.NET MVC3 partial view. How can I escape the content returned from the Html.Partial method to a valid JS string?

I'm looking for something like:

document.write(@Html.JavascriptEscapedPartial("/Shared/_AdContent"))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
document.write('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_AdContent").ToHtmlString()))')
```

Comment: Made my day, Thanks)!